# Unable to install data.table in R version 3.4.1

Tags: c, r, linux, gcc

Following is the message that I'm getting.

> trying URL
>   'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.10.4-3.tar.gz'
>
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3071833 bytes (2.9 MB)
>
> ==================================================
>
> downloaded 2.9 MB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
>
> ** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> ** libs
>
> gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include 
>   -fopenmp -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c wrappers.c -o wrappers.o
>
> gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o
>   data.table.so assign.o between.o bmerge.o chmatch.o dogroups.o
>   fastmean.o fcast.o fmelt.o forder.o frank.o fread.o fsort.o fwrite.o
>   gsumm.o ijoin.o init.o inrange.o openmp-utils.o quickselect.o
>   rbindlist.o reorder.o shift.o subset.o transpose.o uniqlist.o vecseq.o
>   wrappers.o -fopenmp -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
>
> gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [data.table.so] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’

I found this file at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/libgomp.spec. Copied this file to /usr/lib64/R/lib and /usr/local/lib64. Also provided sudo chmod 777 to both locations. Restarted rstudio-server and r session. Still getting the same error.

Comment: have you tried installing the binary instead of compiling from source?

Comment: have you tried quit R and than install data.table package? It is possible it is used by some other package (that is attached).

Comment: Have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998558/gcc-error-libgomp-spec-no-such-file-or-directory-with-amazon-linux-2017-09-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following symbolic links worked.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/libgomp.spec /usr/lib64/libgomp.spec
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/libgomp.a /usr/lib64/libgomp.a
ln -s /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib64/libgomp.so
```