# How to install fields package in RStudio in Amazon EC2?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I need to use the `fields` package in R.

R/RStudio are installed in an Amazon EC2 instance.

I am using R 3.4.

I can't install `fields` package because R can't install `spam` and `dotCall64` packages.

I tried to install the packages manually using the package archive files, but didn't work as well.

If I try to install `dotCall64` directly, I get this:

> gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [dotCall64.so] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dotCall64’

Comment: What do you mean by "R can't install spam and dotCall64 packages" ? Was there an error message when you tried `install.packages("fields", dependencies = TRUE)` and if so, what was it ?

Comment: @neilfws Yes, there is an error message when I try `install.packages("fields", dependencies = TRUE)` or  `install.packages("dotCall64")` directly. The error is the same for both. The error message is that one in written in the question.

Comment: Some suggested solutions are [adding symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108080/unable-to-install-data-table-in-r-version-3-4-1?rq=1) or [installing gcc64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998558/gcc-error-libgomp-spec-no-such-file-or-directory-with-amazon-linux-2017-09-1) or [downgrading gcc to version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616248/install-rjava-package-on-aws-ec2-instance).

Comment: Did you try to remove `$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)` from the `dotCall64/src/Makevars` file?