# -fopenmp does not include omp.h on amazon linux?

Tags: amazon-web-services, compilation, openmp

I'm trying to compile a test openmp program on an Amazon AWS t2.micro instance. It seems to have trouble. Upon trying to compile [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_hello.c) OpenMP hello world program, the compiler fails to find omp.h despite using `gcc hello_world.c -fopenmp`.

After that, I tried running `locate omp.h` and found it in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/include`. I next attempted to compile by including that directory with `gcc -I`. Then, the compiler still needed `libgomp.spec`, which has been encountered and solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998558/gcc-error-libgomp-spec-no-such-file-or-directory-with-amazon-linux-2017-09-1) stack overflow question.

Following the most upvoted answer on there by creating some symbolic links did nothing for me and still says `error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory`, even though `libgomp.spec` is in my `/usr/lib64` directory.

So, what can I do to fix this, and why won't `-fopenmp` work on amazon linux like expected? This is done on an instance which was created by CfnCluster, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, header files such as omp.h come with relevant version of gcc compiler. When the compiler can't find the header file, I guess you are using the different version compiler (other than 4.8.5 in this case).

You can find all gcc versions by typing:

```
sudo yum list installed | grep gcc
```

If there are other versions of gcc such as gcc72, you can erase them by:

```
sudo yum erase gcc72
```

After that, you will compile the code successfully.

Comment: You could check the gcc installation you have chosen by 'gcc -v' to see if it was built with libgomp support.  If not, there will be no omp.h in the installation.  If it is, you might have better luck if you would place the -fopenmp option where it belongs in the command line. The option to build gcc with OpenMP support has been there since gcc 4.7, but I would agree with the previous comment to the extent that OpenMP usage makes current versions advisable.

Comment: Currently, we can install three versions of gcc from yum repository on Amazon Linux. Gcc 4.8 and 6.4 are compiled with libgomp, but 7.2 is not. I don't know why 7.2 is not compiled with libgomp. I assume that both 4.8 and 7.2 are installed in Gravin's instance, so -fopenmp option fails.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, as told  @S.Takezawa , currently only gcc 6.4 installation supports libgomp (fopenmp) and supports modern c++14 standard on Amazon AMI linux.
gcc4.7 is too old. So this helps for me:

```
 sudo yum install gcc64-c++.x86_64 libgcc64.x86_64
```